# Better way of saying "People you may be interested in"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In my website i have system that finds people for you based on your hobbies/interests.Now I have text there that says "People you may be interested in",but it sounds kinda sexual.Is there better or less sexual way of saying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What people may deem sexual can be hard to predict.

So you could straight away suggest
People that match your variable x

Example. People that match your interests

If you have a recommendation algorithm that puts different weights on user attributes and perhaps even individual weights on attributes per user you could suggest a user-specific attribute.

Otherwise you could make it more vague, ie people that match you or people like you/people similar to you.

Comment: People that match your interests seem great:).Thanks for the answer and have a great day!

Comment: I prefer, *people **who** match your interest*. "**that**" sounds rather colloquial.

Comment: Jon Snow, it is customary to upvote the answer you accept. Unless that you upvoted it as an answer you'd accept but you actually don't like the answer. I upvoted the answer.